# Non-consecutive slicing of a multidimensional array in Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am trying to perform non-consectuitive slicing of a multidimensional array like this (Matlab peudo code)

```
 A = B(:,:,[1,3],[2,4,6]) %A and B are two 4D matrices
```

But when I try to write this code in Python:

```
A = B[:,:,np.array([0,2]),np.array([1,3,5])] #A and B are two 4D arrays
```

it gives an error: IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast...

It should be noted that slicing for one dimension each time works fine!

Comment: You should include `A` and `B` in your question, as well as your expected output

Comment: What is B? list or numpy array?

Comment: That piece of code can't give you that error. The only indexing arrays are `np.array([0,2])` and `np.array([1,3])` which _can_ be broadcast together, It wouldn't do what it does in matlab, and the indices are off, but it shouldn't give you that error. Please come up with a proper [mcve] and run it to check that it reproduces your problem.

Comment: You should post full example that produces this error

Comment: You need `np.ix_`. [One relevant duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393140/matlab-like-array-indexing-with-numpy), [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027024/slicing-multi-dimensional-numpy-arrays-with-arrays). The _top-voted_ answer to the former shows how to use it. Also don't forget that while MATLAB indices are 1-based, numpy indices are 0-based.

Comment: @AndrasDeak. I were wrong in the above code. The two indexing vectors are different in length.

Comment: Are you trying index a block with those 2 arrays, or just 2 or 3 points (diagonal like)?

Answer (score 2):

In `numpy`, if you use more than one fancy index (i.e. `array`) to index different dimension of the same array at the same time, they must broadcast. This is designed such that indexing can be more powerful. For your situation, the simplest way to solve the problem is indexing twice:

```
B[:, :, [0,2]] [..., [1,3,5]]
```

where `...` stands for as many `:` as possible.

Indexing twice this way would generate some extra data moving time. If you want to index only once, make sure they broadcast (i.e. put fancy indices on different dimension):

```
B[:, :, np.array([0,2])[:,None], [1,3,5]]
```

which will result in a `X by Y by 2 by 3` array. On the other hand, you can also do

```
B[:, :, [0,2], np.array([1,3,5])[:,None]]
```

which will result in a `X by Y by 3 by 2` array. The `[1,3,5]` axis is transposed before the `[0,2]` axis.

Yon don't have to use `np.array([0,2])` if you don't need to do fancy operation with it. Simply `[0,2]` is fine.

`np.array([0,2])[:,None]` is equivalent to `[[0],[2]]`, where the point of `[:,None]` is to create an extra dimension such that the shape becomes `(2,1)`. Shape `(2,)` and `(3,)` cannot broadcast, while shape `(2,1)` and `(3,)` can, which becomes `(2,3)`.